# Find the factors of $(a+b+c)^3-(b+c-a)^3-(c+a-b)^3-(a+b-c)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the factors of

> $$(a+b+c)^3-(b+c-a)^3-(c+a-b)^3-(a+b-c)^3$$

the answer is $24abc$

Let $E = (a+b+c)^3-(b+c-a)^3-(c+a-b)^3-(a+b-c)^3$

Since $b+c = a $ makes $E = 0, \therefore (b+c-a)$ is one factor, similarly $(c+a-b)$ and $(a+b-c)$ are factors, but can not proceed further :(

Comment: If you expand it out, you get exactly 24abc.

Comment: Is $b+c = a$ given in the problem?

Comment: @user230452, No

Comment: $E = 24abc$ . That's it.

Comment: Can you explain why$  b+c = a $makes $E = 0$?

Comment: @SS_C4 Is there any enlightened way to expand this other than brute force?

Comment: I used brute force.(At least my computer did)

Comment: @user230452, please see my answer below.

Comment: @Vikram, let $a=0$, etc instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle b+c-a=x,c+a-b=y,a+b-c=z\implies x+y+z=a+b+c$

We need $\displaystyle(x+y+z)^3-x^3-y^3-z^3=\{x+(y+z)\}^3-x^3-y^3-z^3$

$\displaystyle=x^3+(y+z)^3+3x(y+z)\{x+(y+z)\}-x^3-y^3-z^3$

$\displaystyle=3yz(y+z)+3x(y+z)\{x+(y+z)\}$

$\displaystyle=3(y+z)\{yz+x(x+y+z)\}$

$$\displaystyle\implies(x+y+z)^3-x^3-y^3-z^3=3(y+z)(z+x)(x+y)$$

Now $y+z=2a$ etc.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 6):

**@user230452** asks for an *enlightened way* of doing this.

The expression 
$$
E = E(a, b, c) = (a+b+c)^3-(b+c-a)^3-(c+a-b)^3-(a+b-c)^3
$$
is symmetric in $a, b, c$, and homogeneous of total degree $3$, so [it must be an integral combination of the elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $a, b, c$, of the form
$$
E = x \sigma_{1}^{3} + y \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} + z \sigma_{3},
$$
for suitable integers $x, y, z$. Here $\sigma_{1} = a + b + c$, $\sigma_{2} = ab + ac + bc$, $\sigma_{3} = a b c$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in $a, b, c$.

Set in order

- $a = b = c = 1$,
- $a = b = 1$, $c = 0$,
- $a = 1$, $b = c = 0$

to get
$$
\begin{cases}
3 x + 9 y + z &= E(1, 1, 1) &=24\\
2 x + 2 y &= E(1, 1, 0) &=0\\
x &= E(1, 0, 0) &=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Hence $x = y = 0$, $z = 24$, and the expression evaluates to $$E = 24 \sigma_{3} = 24 a b c.$$

Comment: This is the way! A possibly interesting modification to the ending is to observe that the substitution $a\mapsto -a$ alters the sign of that sum of cubes (the same holds for $b$ or $c$). I think that rules out the possibilities other than a constant multiple of $abc$. Not sure it's worth our while to look at that closer, because we still need to figure out the constant $24$, and plugging in suitable values for $a,b,c$ is fast anyway :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I think yours is **the** way (the one in **The Book**). I thought *very vaguely* in the same direction, but then went the lazy way ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This technique comes from **A Course in Pure Mathematics** by **Margaret M. Gow**:

$E=(a+b+c)^{3}-(b+c-a)^{3}-(c+a-b)^{3}-(a+b-c)^{3}$

$c=0 \implies E=(a+b)^{3}-(b-a)^{3}-(a-b)^{3}-(a+b)^{3}=0$

$\therefore c$ is a factor of $E$.

By symmetry, $a, b$ also are factors of $E$.

Since $E$ is cubic, let $E=kabc$ where $k$ is a constant.

Take $a=b=c=1$, $E=24=k$.

$\therefore E=24abc$

Comment: I am looking at the book's content, don't know why an algebra book is titled "pure" ?

Comment: @Vikram That's a text book for Pure Mathematics of Advanced Level.  It also concludes Calculus and Coordinate Geometry.  It really is a classic.